# SQL to find missing steps

Tags: presto

I have a case where I want to write a SQL to find what users have a missing set of sequential events. For example, every acquired users should have to go thru (initiation, show design, accept proposal, inspection, installation, and complete).

But some times we have logging gaps that skips on logging some of these steps. Below is the example of existing data and expected data

Input:

| user | event | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | initiation | 2023-03-01 |
| Sam | inspection | 2023-03-01 |
| Sam | complete | 2023-03-01 |

Output:

| user | event | date | is available? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | initiation | 2023-03-01 | yes |
| Sam | show design | null. | no |
| Sam | accept proposal | null. | no |
| Sam | inspection | 2023-03-01 | yes |
| Sam | installation | null | no |
| Sam | complete | 2023-03-01 | yes |

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Presto, but hope below approach is helpful.

```sql
-- sample data
with events (user, event, date) as (
  values('Sam', 'initiation', '2023-03-01'),
        ('Sam', 'inspection', '2023-03-01'),
        ('Sam', 'complete', '2023-03-01')
)

-- the suggested query
select u.user, t.event, e.date, e.date is not null as is_available from (
  select distinct user from events
) u,
unnest (
  array['initiation', 'show design', 'accept proposal',
        'inspection', 'installation', 'complete'] 
) t (event) left join events e on user = e.user and t.event = e.event;
```

**Query results**

[image]

- tested on https://demo.gethue.com/ - Trino(Presto SQL)